# fill up table view with data from parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a class of type UIViewController with UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. I also have a button and a TextField.
If I click the button, i send some Data to Parse.com and I then want the data to be displayed in the TableView so I think I have to reload it.
When the app is starting, i want to load all the data in the tableview - i think I have to do this in viewDidLoad().

I wrote a class for this

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class DataHandler {
    var className : String

    init(className : String) {
        self.className = className
    }

    func getAllObjects() -> AnyObject {

        var output : AnyObject
        var query = PFQuery(className:className)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil && objects != nil {
                var output = objects
            } else {
                println("Error getting data from \(self.className)")
            }
        }
        return output
    }

}
```

but this is not working

Comment: What kind of "not working"?

Comment: for return output i get "Variable 'output' used before being initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getAllObjects` function will return before the **background** query runs.  That means you're returning `output` before anything is written into it.

Also, you've defined two different `var output` variables in different scopes.  What you're assigning to in the block isn't the same as what's defined at the start of the method.

`getAllObjects` shouldn't return anything.  Let the completion handler do the work of using `objects` in whatever way the app needs them.